Subsidiary filter on item workflow
I want to create an item workflow what will set some default values during the creation of the item. The issue is that I want this to happen only for certain subsidiaries. I don't see 'subsidiary' as a possible criteria on the 'condition' field.
That's a bit strange. I'd expect this available if the workflow is supposed to fire on 'after submit' when the subsidiary should be know to the workflow.

Apparently, using a saved search as a criteria is a way to go. The state I used is set for 'after record submit'.
